# Best way for having multilanguage data on Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

What is the best way for having multi-language data on Database.

I want to provide data of cities and the rules is title *can't be null*(if we add new language, we will provide translate of it too)

Look at image please, part B is easily to provide, edit and load
[image]
But I don't know part B works fine for big data or not

Comment: MySql and Sql Server are two different and competing database engines that take very different approaches to this particular problem. We need to know which one you're actually using. I'll come back in a few minutes and if you haven't fixed the tags, I'll have to downvote and vote to close as "unclear".

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It's Sql Server, but I was thinking this question is about all of them

Comment: I would go with design A.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Can you explain why you choose A please?

Comment: Not right now, I don't have the time. I hope to get to it later and write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you ever possibly have a situation where a new language is phased in? There are a lot of advantages to a design similar to `A` but with a fallback/default language in the main table.

This then means that the new language can be added into the auxiliary table and be immediately "usable" even if only half of the translations are available yet.

It also means that a new language doesn't require schema changes.